# C++ Linker error on Release but not Debug

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c++17

I am creating a class that wraps over library function calls in an attempt to obfuscate the imports by walking the PEB and retrieving their addresses manually. I'm able to get this to work.

However, when changing from MSVC x64 Debug to x64 Release, I get a linker error:

> unable to resolve external symbol

Presumably when trying to deduce the call type.

The project is rather large, but I have some watered down code that replicates the problem:

```cpp
template <auto FN>
class FuncWrapper
{
public:
    using T = decltype(FN);
    __forceinline FuncWrapper(T p)
        :
        m_fn(p)
    {
    }
    __forceinline ~FuncWrapper()
    {
        m_fn = nullptr;
    }

    T m_fn;

    __forceinline operator T() { return m_fn; }
};

template<auto FN>
decltype(FN) GetFuncFromPEB(const char *name)
{
    // Walk PEB and loaded DLLs
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    HWND one{};
    GUID* two{};
    LPVOID three{};

    // This is a macro, but I've unwrapped it for legibility
    LONG result = [&]() {
        static FuncWrapper<::WinVerifyTrust> WinVerifyTrust(GetFuncFromPEB<::WinVerifyTrust>("WinVerifyTrust"));
        return WinVerifyTrust(one, two, three);
    }();
}
```

I've tried copying the exact linker command-line parameters, but the problem is the same, so I guess the problem isn't with the linker?

I'm a bit confused because when I add `#pragma comment(lib, "wintrust.lib)`, everything works like normal, and wintrust (and thus `WinVerifyTrust`) isn't even imported. So this becomes an annoyance rather than a problem.

Using Visual Studio 2022 and C++20, Windows 10.0.22621.

**EDIT:** (Until I have the rep to answer my own question)

Managed to solve the problem on my own. Turns out that passing the library function as a parameter in the template trips up the linker (I guess). I had to rewrite the wrapper class to handle function types instead of the functions themselves.

Resolution code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class FuncWrapper
{
public:
    __forceinline FuncWrapper(T p)
        :
        m_fn(p)
    {
    }
    __forceinline ~FuncWrapper()
    {
        m_fn = nullptr;
    }

    T m_fn;

    __forceinline operator T() { return m_fn; }
};

template<typename T>
T GetFuncFromPEB(const char *name)
{
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    HWND one{};
    GUID* two{};
    LPVOID three{};

    // This is a macro, but I've unwrapped it for legibility
    LONG result = [&]() {
        static FuncWrapper<decltype(&::WinVerifyTrust)> WinVerifyTrust(GetFuncFromPEB<decltype(&::WinVerifyTrust)>("WinVerifyTrust"));
        return WinVerifyTrust(one, two, three);
    }();
}
```

Comment: What is the EXACT error message, verbatim?

Comment: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol WinVerifyTrust and
LNK1120 1 unresolved externals

Comment: There are two `WinVerifyTrust` symbols in your code - the Win32 API function, and your wrapper. I'm assuming the linker is complaining about the Win32 API one. Which explains why the `#pragma` fixes the error, since you have to link against the import `.lib` which defines that function. But then you say that "*wintrust (and thus `WinVerifyTrust`) isn't even imported*", which makes no sense because your code is literally using the `WinVerifyTrust` API function, so it MUST be imported.

Comment: Right, I see that issuing a `#pragma` fixes the error, but it *does not get imported*. I promise. I threw the binary into PeStudio and there is no reference to wintrust in the libraries tab, nor does `WinVerifyTrust` exist in the function imports.

Comment: I think I've solved it, kinda. Played around with it. Turns out passing the library function as a parameter in the template trips up the linker. I had rewrite the wrapper class and declare the template parameter as a typename, then pass `decltype(&::WinVerifyTrust)` to it. Which works. Will edit main post.

Comment: "*Will edit main post*" - please don't do that. Post your solution as an answer instead, see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).